# Gerar chave ssh no git

Tags: git, github

Estou precisando de uma ajuda!

Esses dias estava na faculdade, fazendo commit de alguns projetos no meu repositorio no **GitHub** através do **Git**, e subindo alguns arquivos no repositório, quando fui subir o ultimo e dar **git push**, deu um certo erro:

> **Error: Permission denied (publickey)**

Eu tentei via **HTTP e SSH** e os dois não foram, primeira vez que tive este problema.

Eu já olhei alguns passos na internet, tanto vídeos como tutorial, fiz alguns e continuava a mesma coisa, com o erro da chave não permitida quando estava nesta máquina lá na faculdade.

Vi que tinha que configurar no profile do meu `Git o SSH` das máquinas que são permitidas de `chaves públicas e prívadas` para eu usar o **Git local** e enfim, não consegui!
De qualquer forma, se alguém poder me ajudar, mostrando realmente um **passo-a-passo**, sabendo gerar `SSH` para poder habiltiar o uso em outra máquina e poder ser usado, me ajudará muito! Alguns passos que vi, são quebrados, não são realmente válidos, até do próprio **GitHelp**, não são completo !
Então se me ajudarem mostrando um passo-a-passo vai ajudar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Como você disse, existem duas formas de se autenticar no GitHub quando você faz um push: via HTTP e via SSH. Via HTTP você fornece suas credenciais, da mesma forma que as forneceria ao fazer login no site do GitHub; e via SSH, na qual você usa um par de chaves – sendo uma pública e uma privada – para se autenticar sem usuário e senha.

Primeiramente, devemos gerar um novo par de chaves usando o comando `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "seu-email@seu-servidor.com"
```

O comando irá perguntar em qual arquivo você deseja salvar sua chave. Se você não tem nenhuma chave configurada, não tem problema usar o nome padrão (`id_rsa`). Em seguida, ele perguntará se você deseja usar uma senha que será perguntada toda vez que você fizer uma autenticação baseada nas suas chaves. Recomendo configurar uma senha se você compartilha seu computador com outras pessoas.

```
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [digite sua senha]
Enter same passphrase again: [digite sua senha novamente]
```

Finalmente, sua chave será salva na pasta `~/.ssh`:

```
Your identification has been saved in /Users/raffa-ferreira/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/raffa-ferreira/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
01:0f:f4:3b:ca:85:d6:17:a1:7d:f0:68:9d:f0:a2:db seu-email@seu-servidor.com
```

Feito isso, vamos colocar as chaves no GitHub. Logue em sua conta, vá para as configurações de [Chaves SSH](https://github.com/settings/ssh) e clique no botão *Add SSH key*. Lá você terá um campo de título, opcional, e o campo da chave, no qual você deverá colar a chave pública (e não a privada) que acabamos de gerar. Para facilitar o processo, copie a chave pública para a área de transferência usando o comando `pbcopy`:

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Depois da sua chave ter sido configurada no GitHub, já é possível dar um `git push` normalmente.

Comment: Obrigado rodrigo, muito útil seu passo-a-passo e seus comentários, ajudou bastante!