# Armazenar credencias de um repositório Git no Windows sem SSH

Tags: windows, git

Como configurar o Git em um repositório local para que não peça o login e a senha toda vez que for fazer um Push ou Pull?

Meu servidor Git não suporta SSH. Apenas HTTP.
Tenho somente o *username* e a *password* de usuário no Git.

Comment: http://oraculum.blog.br/blogoraculum/index.php/salvar-senha-do-git-no-windows-com-git-credential-winstore/ da uma olhada nesse  link

Comment: Qual S.O.? Windows ou Linux?

Comment: Windows @MarcosRegis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem duas possibilidades.

#### Acessando o repositório via SSH

Configure eu projeto para acessar o repositório usando um par de chave pública e chave privada.

Primeiro você deve alterar o *origin* para acessar o repositório remoto por meio do protocolo SSH ao invés do protocolo HTTPS (esse caminho você vê na página do repositório):

```
git remote set-url origin git://<caminho do seu repositório>
```

Depois você deve criar um par de chave pública e chave privada, e configurá-los no Github (ou no serviço de Git que você usa). [Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81045/gerar-chave-ssh-no-git/81176#81176) eu explico direitinho como fazê-lo.

#### Usando o credencial helper

O Git ainda dá a possibilidade de [armazenar seu usuário e senha em um *keychain*](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) próprio, se modo que você possa usar HTTPS e não precise informá-los em todo `git pull` e `git push`.

A única coisa que você precisa fazer é informar ao Git para usar o keychain do sistema operacional. Abaixo os procedimentos para cada um deles.

Linux:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

OSX:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

Windows:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Depois disso é só clonar o repositório via HTTPS (ou fazer qualquer operação que exija conexão, como `git pull` ou `git push`), informar usuário e senha, e o Git nunca mais os perguntará novamente.

PS: o credencial helper só está disponível na versão 1.7.10 para cima; verifique a versão do Git instalada com `git -v`.

Comment: Esqueci de colocar na pergunta meu servidor Git não suporta SSH. Somente tenho o "username" e a "senha" para usar o servidor do Git.

Comment: Entendi. Alterei a resposta para suas necessidades.

Comment: Digitei o comando do *credential helper*, mas não deu nenhuma opção a mais para digitar as credenciais.

Comment: A única coisa que você precisa fazer é informar ao Git para usar o keychain do sistema operacional. No caso do Linux esse comando é `git config --global credential.helper cache`; no OSX é `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain`; e no Windows é `git config --global credential.helper wincred`. Depois disso é só clonar o repositório via HTTPS, informar usuário e senha, e o Git nunca mais os perguntará novamente.

Comment: Legal. Funcionou! Creio que é interessante colocar esses comandos na sua resposta, pois a solução vai estar imediatamente disponível para outros que aqui chegarem. Vlw!

Comment: Legal, valeu! Complementei a resposta conforme sua sugestão. :)

Answer (score 2):

Se for msysgit em Windows 7 e não se preocupar em ter sua senha de forma aberta em um arquivo use este método.

Abra um prompt de comando e execute:

```
setx HOME %USERPROFILE%
```

A variável %HOME% será criada com o valor `'C:\Users\SEU USUARIO'`

Agora abra esse diretório e crie um arquivo com o nome ***_netrc*** com o seguinte conteúdo

```
machine <hostname>
login <login>
password <password>
```

Comment: Fiz o que escreveu mas não foi.

Comment: como ficou seu arquivo _netrc?

Comment: Ficou assim: machine https://gitlab...
login meuUsername
password minhaSenha