# Como salvar as credenciais do Git no Linux?

Tags: git

No meu Ubuntu, quando dou um pull, push e etc. O git sempre pede meu usuário e senha. Como faço para isso ficar salvo?

Comment: Possível duplicada (ou parcialmente) de: [Armazenar credencias de um repositório Git no Windows sem SSH](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100596/armazenar-credencias-de-um-reposit%c3%b3rio-git-no-windows-sem-ssh?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Armazenando Permanentemente

Se quiser fazer no terminal, execute os comandos abaixo:

```bash
git config credential.helper store
git push origin main
```

Informe seu usuário e/ou sua senha e aperte <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Após isso, sua senha ficará salva permanentemente.

### Armazenando Temporariamente

Se quiser fazer no terminal, execute os comandos abaixo:

```bash
git config credential.helper cache
git push origin main
```

Informe seu usuário e/ou sua senha e aperte <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Após isso, sua senha ficará salva por 900 segundos. Caso queira aumentar ou diminuir o tempo, utilize a *flag* `--timeout`:

```bash
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout <seconds>'
```

> Observação: Você pode usar a *flag* `--global` após `git` para aplicar a alteração em todos os repositórios locais

### No Windows

No Windows, você pode usar o [Git Credential Manager Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core) para gerenciar suas credenciais.

Comment: Funcionou aqui.
Vlw Valdeir Psr