# Como configurar o GIT remoto no Amazon AWS?

Tags: git, amazon-aws

fiz uma conta no AWS e estou com dificuldades em organizar e configurar os arquivos de repositórios com GIT.

Já tenho o APACHE, PHP e MYSQL e GIT instalados. Criei uma pasta /var/git para organizar os repositórios, e subpastas para cada cliente: git/cliente1/

Inicializei o repositório com "git --bare init" dentro de /git/cliente1/cliente1.git

Inicializei o git localmente nas pastas dos clientes em meu pc (git init) e adicionei o git remoto "git remote add origin usuario@servidor/cliente/cliente1.git"

Porém, quando dou "git push origin master" ele me diz que a public key é inválida (permission denied - public key)

Tentei configurar a public key mas não tive sucesso. Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa criar os repositórios localmente, comitar os arquivos, enviar para o repositório remoto e só então cloná-los na sua instância AWS.

Antes de mais nada, crie os repositórios remotos no serviço de sua preferência (Github, Bitbucket etc).

Depois, para que você possa enviar seus repositórios locais para seus repositórios correspondentes remotos, é necessário [criar um par de chaves](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81045/gerar-chave-ssh-no-git) (sendo uma pública e privada) e então fazer o `commit` e, em seguida, o `push`.

Enfim, você pode clonar os repositórios na sua instância AWS. Pode fazê-lo usando o mesmo chaves privada/pública, ou usando [deploy keys](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/). A diferença é que uma deploy key te dá acesso a um único repositório, enquanto que as chaves privada/pública te dão acesso a todos os repositórios do seu usuário. Vai da sua própria necessidade.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Rodrigo. Sim, criei os repositórios remotos, depois criei os repositórios locais, adicionei, comitei. Mas o meu problema parece ser registrar as chaves públicas dentro do servidor da AWS. Nesse link que colocou, o exemplo é com o bitbucket ou github, lá tem os locais próprios, é tranquilo. Mas na Amazon, estou meio perdido onde insiro as chaves para me autenticar.

Comment: Não precisa inserir chave em nenhum lugar. Basta gerá-las dentro da instância usando o comando `ssh-keygen`, copiar a chave pública que será salva (por padrão) no arquivo `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` e configurá-la no seu perfil do serviço Git, da mesma forma que você configurou sua chave pessoal.

Comment: E ai, conseguiu resolver?