# Github com usuário e senha automáticos

Tags: github

Como fazer git memorizar usuário e senha, pra não ter que digitar toda vez que for fazer atualização em projeto?

Comment: Seu email está configurado? exemplo *git config --global user.email "fulano@email.com"* ?

Comment: Sim, e mesmo assim pede email e senha

Comment: Provavelmente isto resolva https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

Comment: Só usar SSH ao invés de HTTPS que você não vai precisar digitar senha.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento resolveu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que vc precisa entender o que existe duas duas formas de usar git, não importa o lugar do repositório, que são: via `https` e `ssh`, se vc usar `https`, vai precisa colocar a senha toda vez que usar. Se usar com `ssh` não precisa colocar a senha.

Gerando a chave pública
[Gerar chave ssh no git](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81045/gerar-chave-ssh-no-git)

E se você usar o github como agregador de código então veja esse artigo.
https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/