# Erro na hora de realizar um push para o GitHub

Tags: git, github

Preciso realizar um `push` de arquivos da minha máquina para o GitHub mas não estou conseguindo.

Deixo abaixo algumas linhas de código que usei no `cmd` tentando realizar o `commit`, `push`, `git init` e tudo que todos falam mas nada funcionou:

```
> git remote add origin git@github.com:gabriegsti/C

> git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

> git add *

> git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

> git commit -m "aqui coloco uma mensagem, tipo: comitando primeiro post"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

> git push -u origin master
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.112' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

> ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado.
```

Comment: Você está no Windows, confere? Instalou o git como? Pelo último comando que você postou, o sistema não detectou a presença do executável chamado `ssh-keyscan`. A falha dada foi que você não criou sua chave SSH na sua máquina e não enviou a parte pública para o GitHub

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Gerar chave ssh no git](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81045/gerar-chave-ssh-no-git)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem vindo ao [pt.stackoverflow.com](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).
Partindo da premissa que você tem efetuado a configuração de `SSH`(*passo fundamental para utilizar o Git*) em sua máquina com o repositório *Git*.

Vamos analisar o seu cenário e a sequência de comandos do qual utilizou.

```
 1. git remote add origin
 2. git status
 3. git add *
 4. git commit -m "sua mensagem de commit"
 5. git push -u origin master
```

`1.` Possívelmente seu `git remote` não estabeleceu uma sincronização entre seu repositório local e o remoto, note que links remotos possuem a extensão `.git` ao final de seu *path*, diferentemente do seu(*git@github.com:gabriegsti/C*). Para verificar se o repositório realmente foi sincronizado, utilize o comando `git remote -v` e veja se o **origin** foi exibido, juntamente com seu destino.
 `2/3.` Antes de commitar sua alteração é válido verificar quais arquivos foram modificados(`git status`) e (`git add *`) para adicioná-los ao status de `staged`, perfeitamente correto antes de realizar o `commit`. Pórem, note que o *Git* ainda lhe ajuda dando uma mensagem de help avisando que não há nenhum arquivo alterado(*nothing to commit, working tree clean*), provavelmente por não manter sincronismo proporcionado pelo passo 1.
 `4.` Observe que não há nada para ser commitado, mais uma vez e o *Git* tenta avisá-lo(*nothing to commit, working tree clean*).
 `5.` A mensagem relacionada ao `push`, está referente à configuração de chave `SSH`, você pode realizar o teste de conexão para analisar sua severidade. Indico realizar [os seguintes passos](https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection). E também verificar em seu cenário se realmente é necessário utilizar o parâmetro `-u` em seu `push`.

Verifique se a descrição acima está de acordo com o seu ambiente e lembre-se de realizar as configurações iniciais e necessárias para iniciar com o Git. Como você mesmo mencionou que não sabe muito sobre essa tecnologia, indico dar uma lida [aqui](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) e [aqui](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2).

Comment: Ao usa o "git remote -v" dentro da pasta que eu quero enviar o meu trabalho, ele me mostra o repositorio certo no git hub. Então passei ao passo 2, o status ainda tem a resposta de "nothing to commit working tree clean".

Comment: Essa mensagem `nothing to commit working tree clean`, indica que o *Git* não identificou nenhuma alteração sua no repositório.

Comment: Então passei ao passo 5, obtive a seguinte resposta:
C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\Faculdade\estudo_em_c>git push origin master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Obs: Eu fui pesquisar mais sobre ssh, mas creio que configurei isto no inicio da instalação, pelo menos o diretório com esta chave consta nos meus usuários. Gostaria de saber se há algum relação de nomes ou pastas com o git pois eu tenho um pasta no meu pc que é "estudo_com_c" que tem o git init(.git) pois executei dentro dela, e tenho um repositorio que criei pelo github chamado "C" somente. Mas como criei os dois separados e ambos tem nomes diferentes. eu queria saber se esse pode ser o problema.

Comment: você não precisa pesquisar, você fez tudo que recomendei em minha resposta(inclusive acessar e analisar os links que estão lá)?

Comment: Sim, inclusive quando utilizei "git remote -v" a orgin aparecceu correta.

Comment: Você lembra de ter configurado seu `GitHub` com a chave de acesso **SSH** que criou?

Comment: Não lembro. Só constatei que ela existe. Infelizmente por falta de conhecimento não dei atenção nessa parte no momento em que instalei.

Comment: Vamos fazer o seguinte, vou convidá-lo ao chat ok?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91907/discussion-between-andre-filipe-and-gabriel-silva).

Answer (score 6):

Uma possível solução seria autenticar via *http* e não *ssh*.

**Exemplo:**

Na página do seu repositório, faça o seguinte, selecione *https* e copie a *url*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apos copiar, atualize a *url* do repositório remoto.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/renantins/test.git
```

Quando realizar o `push`, será necessário incluir o seu usuário e senha do GitHub.

Comment: Definitivamente não a resposta que eu esperaria ver, hahaha!

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado :)