# Push no git não esta vinculado a minha conta

Tags: git, github

estou fazendo alguns estudos e usando o git para armazená-los, quando vou dar um push na master, meu git até da esse push, mas não em nome do meu usuário do git hub 
Esse é meu usuario do git:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E é nesse nome que esta sendo publicado:
[image: gith]

Se não tiver ficado tão claro eu tento explicar melhor pelos comentários

Comment: Pelo que cosigo enxergar, meu GitHub não esta conversando com o Git

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa [postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/372937/erro-na-hora-de-realizar-um-push-para-o-github/372954#372954) Ravel!

Comment: @AndréFilipe Meu problema estava relacionado ao vinculo do github com git, consegui resolver com o link que postei na resposta. Mas mesmo assim, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A todos que tiverem o mesmo problema, acabei de achar a solucão neste link: http://gabsferreira.com/instalando-o-git-e-configurando-github/

Créditos totais ao autor!